# how to explode a string and make an echo of a chosen attribute

Tags: php

I have a string containing ; subdivided by , and would like to make an echo of a chosen value.

My string is `$string='Width,10;Height,5;Size,1,2,3'`

I want to make an echo of the Height value (echo result must be 5)

Answer (score 2):

```
$parts = explode(';', $string);
$component = explode(',', $parts[1]); // [1] is the Height,5 portion
echo $component[1]; // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
$p = explode(';', $string);
$data = array();
foreach($p as $part) {
    $split = explode(',',$part,2); //the 'Size' bit different that the rest. I assume 1,2,3 is the value for Size?
    $data[$split[0]] = $split[1];
}
$what_you_want_to_find = 'Height';
echo $data[$what_you_want_to_find];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$attrs = explode(";", $string);
$attrHeight = "";
foreach ($attrs as $value) {

   if (strpos($value, "Height") !== false) 
     $attrHeight = explode(",", $value);

}

echo $attrHeight;
```